# How should Monk's Slow Fall class feature be narrated?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monk, narration

Visualization of feats, effects, spells and abilities in *D&D* is generally somewhat straightforward:

- Paladin's *Smite Evil* - your weapon glows with holy energy and is unleashed when you hit Evil™ in the face,
- Rogue's *Sneak Attack* - you stab them in the soft parts,
- Monk's *Flurry of Blows* - [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vztkMgax7w4) minus the heals.

But I could never understood how Monk's Slow Fall feat should be visualized. The text, [quoting d20srd](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/monk.htm#slowFall), says:

> At 4th level or higher, a monk within arm’s reach of a wall can use it to slow her descent.

Does Monk, like, slams their fist into that wall? Runs up against it? Catches it with teeth? Uses air updrafts?

So - what is the intended visualization behind it?

Comment: @Snappie That sounds like an answer, not a request to clarify the question.  I suggest you post it as an answer.

Comment: I should say that what your asking about are class features, not feats. You may want to replace that tag with monk if the site has it

Comment: @Levi Gah, I forgot about that tag. Fortunately, we have very active moderators.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several ways that this could be done:

- They might just dig their fingers/claw/dagger into the wall, coming down in a dust cloud.
- They might grab for something protruding and make a flip around, rinse and repeat
- They might run DOWN the wall, slowing down at the end and jump off it to do a roll before landing...

But in the end: Let the player narrate his cool monk ability how he would like. It's a monk, this ability is from Kung-Fu- and Ninja-Movies, so... be inspired by them?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike earlier D&D editions 5th ed doesn't mention the need for a monk to be close to a wall or something to slow their fall.  This opens up the game to characters having "mystical chi" slowing their falls like in movies.

In our game we visualize a monk's Slow Fall the same as martial arts movies depict falling characters:  Their clothes flap with the sound of moving wind then they land smoothly like fallen cats.  Picture Crouching Fighter Hidden Dragon or Kung Fu Panda:  The characters are using their Ki (without spending Ki points) rather than scraping at nearby supports.

Comment: This question specifies 3.5, so the 5e rules aren't exactly relevant

Comment: @StephenTG Technically, yes... But still, it's an useful aside. I would have probably made the question specific to whole D&D (perhaps with a sub-question pertaining to the wall thing alone) if I knew that this Monk's feature appears in other editions.